# How to change some values inside a function when we call it?

Tags: javascript

```
function createElems(){
    var post = "<div class='post'>";
    post += "<p>"+area.value+"</p>";
    post +="<img src='default.jpg'>";
    post += "</div>" 
}
```

I have three other functions and i want to remove the p in one and i want them both in the other function

Comment: The function shown has a basic syntax error, varying capitalization of its variable name, and does nothing useful as it just creates a string and then doesn't do anything with it. Please post your an [mcve] of your **actual** code so we can help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameters for this sort of purpose. Like this:

```
function createElems(pOrNot){
    var post = "<div class='post'>";
    if(pOrNot)
    {
        post += "<p>"+area.value+"</p>";
    }
    post +="<img src='default.jpg'>";
    post += "</div>";
}
```

And you can call it like that if you want p tag:

```
createElems(true);
```

But I must say that this function is totally useless. You should explain what is your goal with this function.

Comment: i have three other functions so the user can post paragraph with image or image only or post them both so i want to remove the image if the user chooses to post text only or vise versa

Comment: yes it did thank you, i had to add else if param == false or empty

Comment: You're welcome. Also you don't need to write `if param == false or empty` you can shortly write `if (!param)`. It is way more cleaner.